# How to set correct memory speed in BIOS

Tags: memory, bios, speed, dram

I recently purchased and installed a pair of Vengeance® — 8GB DDR3 Memory Kit (CMZ8GX3M1A1600C10) , these are now the only DIMMs in my system. (Asus P6T Deluxe board - CPU: i7 920)

According to the specs they are capable of 1600Mhz but when runnning CPU-Z I see that the DRAM frequency is 534.5Mhz

[CPU-Z Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8AqK.png)

Googled for info and I ended up trying to figure out how to enable XMP Profile. Unfortunately, after various attempts and value changes in BIOS, the only thing that I managed was to render the system unbootable.

Tried the following DIMM combinations :
in Sockets A1 & B1  and  in Sockets A2 & A1

Is there any kind of guide or information on how to set this up? Maybe some extra reading about other settings that I may have to do before changing memory?

[BIOS Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu09H.jpg)

Comment: The memory may be able to run at 800MHz (in salesdroid terms 1600MHz) but the memory controller on the CPU has an official max speed of 533MHz (DDR1066). See https://ark.intel.com/products/37147/Intel-Core-i7-920-Processor-8M-Cache-2_66-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI for specs.

Comment: Ther instructions are in the [manual](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P6T_Deluxe/HelpDesk_Manual/). Sections 2.4 tells you which slots to use. You can definitely run the RAM at 1600 MHz - I have exactly that in this computer with a P6T-SE board.

Comment: ... I just rebooted to check: on the AI Tweaker page, change the DRAM Frequency to 1600 MHz. I have the rest of the RAM settings on Auto.

Comment: Already tried that but the system doesn't boot. Can you post a screenshot of your BIOS screen and the DIMM positions you used?

Comment: Are you using the latest BIOS version? Perhaps you need to reset the BIOS to "Safe defaults" (remember any other stuff, like disk drive settings, before you do that) and then configure the memory speed. The manual explicitly recommends to use slots A1 and B1 if you are installing two RAM sticks. Does it work at 1333 MHz?

Comment: Thanks but I do use the latest BIOS update. I have already tried 1333 but didn't work, didn't even boot.

Answer (score 0):

I basically have the same specs as you and I literally had the same problems and simply went into the bios and changed the ram to "X.M.P"